# Propel method update is undefined?

Tags: php, propel

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
$post = PostQuery::create()
    ->findPk($id);

$post->update($params);
```

The method is taken from http://propelorm.org/documentation/03-basic-crud.html, but I receice an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message 'Call to undefined method: update' in /usr/share/php/propel/om/BaseObject.php:426

What could I've done wrong in this case? I can delete successfully with the delete-method using in the same way:

```
$post = PostQuery::create()
        ->findPK($id);

$post->delete();
```

---

**Update**

I tried the mentioned solutions, the first one works well, but not the second one.

```
$post = PostQuery::create()
    ->filterById($id)
    ->update($params);
```

This now throws another error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PropelException' with message 'Cannot
>   fetch ColumnMap for undefined column phpName: id' in
>   /usr/share/php/propel/map/TableMap.php:384

although the schema.xml looks correct to me:

```
 <table name="post" phpName="Post" idMethod="native">
    <column name="id" phpName="Id" type="INTEGER" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" required="true"/>
```

I don't know what could be the problem here as I am able to fetch the id by using the find()-method and

```
$post->getId();
```

while looping through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update this way.

In your case, you should do something like this (if `$params` is a key => value array with modified value):

```
$post = PostQuery::create()
    ->findPk($id);

$post->fromArray($params);
$post->save();
```

Or you can do it quickly:

```
$post = PostQuery::create()
    ->filterById($id)
    ->update($params);
```

Your solution doesn't work because you already retrieve the object using `find()`. If you want to update an object you already retrieved, you have to use `save()` method (and not `update()`). But if you don't rerieve the object, you can make an update in one query, using the `update()` method.

Comment: The first solution works for me, unfortunately not the second, which I would prefer. Maybe you can revisit my updated question for achieving this; in any case thanks for your help and explanation.

Comment: @32bitfloat try `filterByPK` even if `filterById` should work regarding your schema..

Comment: guess you meant `filterByPrimaryKey` (which is recognized by my IDE), as `filterByPK` expects an equally named column (Unknown column Pk in model Post). I'm afraid that using `filterByPrimaryKey` returns in the same error message as stated above in the update. Could it be a problem that many tables use a column named id as primary key? Kinda weird...

Comment: @32bitfloat, I have exactly the same issue as you do and also am going with the ->save() solution for now. Did you ever find out why update() wouldn't work in this case?

Comment: @userfuser the final problem was that the indices in my $params-array didn't match the phpnames given in the schema.xml (case sensitivity), which led to the error 'Cannot fetch ColumnMap...'. So using create()->filterById()->update() now works for me.